# How to detect overflow or line breaks in XSL-FO document rendered with Apache FOP

Tags: java, xml, sax, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a very simple FO document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
    <fo:region-body margin-top="30mm" />
  </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block-container height="10mm" font-size="8mm" overflow="error-if-overflow" wrap-option="wrap">
      <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">Hello W3Schools Hello W3Schools Hello W3Schools sad da sadasd dsaasd</fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Having `overflow` set to `error-if-overflow`, I'll get an error rendering this document. Is there any way of detecting the place of overflow in the text? I'd like to be able to brake this text into many by hand, but I don't like idea of removing one word at a time and reruning rendering just to see if it failes again.

The exception that is get is:

```
Content overflows the viewport of an fo:block-container in block-progression direction by 26078 millipoints. Content will be clipped. (See position 12:103)
```

Unfortunatelly this is the position of `block-container` tag in which the error occured and not a specific word that created overflow.

Comment: Your example contains three 'Hello'.  Being told that the `fo:block` broke on 'Hello' still wouldn't help.  In the general case, the last 'word' before the overflow might not be a 'word' from your text.  E.g., with hyphenation enabled, it might be 'He-', and I don't know what it would be if the overflow was in the middle of some RTL text in a LTR block.  If you're manually adding breaks based on which word was at the break, are you going to be able to take care of widows and orphans, e.g., when the last line of the `fo:block` overflows, will you know where to break after the third last line?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do. Just to clarify, let us suppose that _somehow_ you know that the overflow happens after the first 40 characters: **what are you going to do with this information?** Edit your FO file to remove the characters after the 40th? Edit the whole block so that you say the same thing using fewer than 40 characters? Something else?

Comment: @Ifurini I'm acting upon my custom layout (abstract thing, not connected anyhow to XSL-FO) which have blocks that can flow. If I know, that the overflow happens after 40th character, I'll break the text so that 40 chars go to first block and the rest tries to fit into *flow target* of that block, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr version:

Instead of creating a PDF output, you can use the [FOP's "intermediate format" feature](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/intermediate.html) to create an **XML representation** of the generated pages and areas.

You can then use it as an input to

- check *whether* an overflow happened or not
- check *how many* characters (and / or *which text*) would be placed in the first line, so that you can modify the input file by hand
- automatically rewrite your input file so that the text that would overflow is placed in a different block instead (this is going to be less trivial)

---

### More details:

You can create the Area Tree (AT) output from the command line using

```
fop input.fo -at application/pdf at.xml
```

or you can create the Intermediate Format (IF) output with

```
fop input.fo -if application/pdf if.xml
```

([FOP's site](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/embedding.html#documenthandlers) has details about how to programmatically produce the intermediate format output using Java code).

For example, if your input FO file contains

```
<!--
there is no need for the wrap-option="wrap" attributes, as that is the default value, 
I added an id attribute on the fo:block-container
-->
<fo:block-container id="foo" height="10mm" font-size="8mm" overflow="error-if-overflow">
  <fo:block>Hello W3Schools Hello W3Schools Hello W3Schools sad da sadasd dsaasd</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

the IF output (which is less verbose than the AT one) is like this:

```
...
<page index="0" name="1" page-master-name="A4" width="594720" height="792000">
    <page-header/>
    <content>
        <viewport transform="translate(0,85039)" width="594720" height="706961">
            <viewport width="594720" height="28346" clip-rect="0 0 594720 28346">
                <font family="sans-serif" style="normal" weight="400" variant="normal" size="22677" color="#000000"/>
                <id name="foo"/>
                <text x="0" y="19400">Hello W3Schools Hello W3Schools Hello W3Schools sad</text>
                <text x="0" y="46612">da sadasd dsaasd</text>
            </viewport>
        </viewport>
    </content>
    <page-trailer/>
</page>
...
```

and the XPath `//viewport[id[@name = 'foo']]/text[1]` gives you the text content of the first line.